# My Select2 plugin is not returning any results from php script via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-select2

I have been racking my brain for hours now trying to figure out why this is not working. Thanks in advance for anyone who can help.

Basically, I am trying to use json-encoded data from a php/mysql database query to populate the dropdown for the select2 plugin.

the HTML:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="search-area" id="location-search" data-placeholder="Select an area" style="width:100%"/>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$(".select2").select2();

$("#location-search").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "location-data.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                q: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return { results: data.text };  
        }
    }

}); 
})
```

The PHP Script 'location-data.php':

```
<?php
include 'db/db-connect.php'; 

$query = "SELECT townID, town FROM towns WHERE town LIKE '%a%' ORDER BY town";
$result = $db->query($query);
$numtowns = $result->num_rows;

if($numtowns != 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['townID'], "text"=>$row['town']);
}
}
else {
$answer[] = array("id"=>"0", "text"=>"No Results Found...");    
}
echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

Now i have looked at the location-data.php page in my browser and it is displaying in the correct format, see below.

```
[{"id":"1","text":"basildon"},{"id":"2","text":"billericay"},{"id":"7","text":"eastwood"},{"id":"12","text":"hanningfield"},{"id":"5","text":"maldon"},{"id":"11","text":"ongar"},{"id":"6","text":"rayleigh"}]
```

Whenever I attempt to use the select2 box, all it displays is 'searching...' and never displays results.

Thanks again for any help that can be given.

Comment: Also, I am using a hardcoded search for 'a' just to get it displaying results, once it has done that then I will move on to make the results dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the result function to return data. select2 needs an array of id,text pairs.  i suspect you're seeing a javascript error in your browser that data.text doesn't exist.

```
results: function (data) {
    return { results: data };  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add more:

```
formatResult: formatValues,
formatSelection: selectValues,
```

Create function formatresult and selectValues:

```
function formatValues(data) {
    return data.text;
}

function selectValues(data) {
    return data.id;
}
```